# Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, gumstix, linaro

I'm getting the following error every time I try to run Linaro on Gumstix Overo board. Does anyone had the same issue? I can't figure out what the problem is. Tried to reinstall Linaro several times, but the same error comes out again.

```
 [  455.455841] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000694
[  455.464385] pgd = c0004000
[  455.467224] [00000694] *pgd=00000000
[  455.471008] Internal error: Oops: 80000007 [#1] PREEMPT
[  455.476501] Modules linked in: libertas_sdio libertas cfg80211 rfkill lib80211 ads7846
[  455.484924] CPU: 0    Not tainted  (3.2.1-linaro-omap #3)
[  455.490600] PC is at 0x694
[  455.493469] LR is at handle_level_irq+0x58/0xf8
[  455.498260] pc : [<00000694>]    lr : [<c0092974>]    psr: 200f01b3
[  455.498260] sp : c08bbeb8  ip : c08bbe90  fp : c08bbecc
[  455.510345] r10: 00000000  r9 : 411fc083  r8 : 80004059
[  455.515838] r7 : c08bbf44  r6 : ffffffff  r5 : c08de4d8  r4 : c08de488
[  455.522705] r3 : 00000695  r2 : dec062d0  r1 : 0000000b  r0 : c08de488
[  455.529571] Flags: nzCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA Thumb  Segment kernel
[  455.537536] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 9ddec019  DAC: 00000015
[  455.543579] Process swapper (pid: 0, stack limit = 0xc08ba2f0)
[  455.549713] Stack: (0xc08bbeb8 to 0xc08bc000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It means you are trying to access a NULL pointer in your code. Put NULL checks in your code to find out where.